# Create a string method in Java to input a question

Tags: java

So I have this code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Quiz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String question = "What is cardano?\n";
    question += "A. a place in Italy\n";
    question += "B. a dish using fish\n";
    question += "C. a blockchain protocol\n";
    question += "D. a monastery in Florence\n";
    question += "E. a type of food\n";

    while (true) {
        String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
        answer = answer.toUpperCase();
        if (answer.equals("C")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!");
            break;
        } else if (answer.equals("A") || answer.equals("B") || answer.equals("D") || answer.equals("E")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong. Please try again.");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");
        }
    }
}
```

}

I need to Add a static method that asks a question until the user provides valid input.•Call the method "ask". It should take a String parameter and should return a String. 
`static String ask(String question)`. 
How do I get the input to move to the method ask?

Comment: Your current code is already working like you described ?? But then you have to move it to a new method "ask" ? Is that your question ?

Comment: Yes, instead of using the while loop I have to create a method called ask. This has to take a question and then i have to call the method.

Comment: answer=ask()
while(answer!="C")
{
     if (answer.equals("A") || answer.equals("B") || answer.equals("D") || answer.equals("E")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong. Please try again.");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");
        }
answer=ask();
}
if (answer.equals("C")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!");

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create ask() method and return the input string you received from user.
2. Run your loop based on the answer. i.e. until answer is not equals to "C" in this case.
3. Finally invoke the ask() method at the end again to get the new input from the user
4. Repeat the same process until user inputs "C".

Below is the code:

```
answer = ask();

while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {

     if (answer.equals("A") || answer.equals("B") ||
         answer.equals("D") || answer.equals("E")) 
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong. Please try again.");
     else 
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
             "Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");

     answer = ask();
}

if (answer.equals("C")) 
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!");
```

Comment: misleading answer? I havent received any comment on this yet

Comment: No Problem.I am happy that someone is there to point out the mistakes so I can learn and become a better contributor.

Comment: ok thanks. For some questions, I find answer in other stackoverflow threads or some other website. Is it acceptable that I post that content or the link itself as an answer ?

Comment: If you find that an older answer answers a new question, then you should vote to close the question as a duplicate. Please read [answer] as well as the other relevant sections in the [help].